# What is causing fluctuations in the training accuracy in a categorization problem

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm training a fusion network. I get now these kinds of fluctuations in the training accuracy. I'm not entirely sure what that means. I've read a few answers where it says that it is because the boundaries between the categories are switching and it causes the model to swap between classifying some items correctly. I'm now expanding the training set as well with some augmented data but still quite worried about this.

My training set is fairly small - only 348 images. This is what is worrying me that it might be a sign of overfitting. The loss on the training set continues to go down and I stop training when the validation loss flattens using early stopping. The results are quite good on the test set but I'm just worried about this fluctuation.

Edit: The model minimizes categorical cross entropy using the Adam optimizer.

Edit 2: Loss

Edit 3: After adding the augmented images to the training set/testing set/validation set it smooths out:

Pictures before and after augmentation, wondering why first picture includes so many fluctuations.

[image: loss]

[image]

Comment: Can you add the y-axis scale? Perhaps it's simply noise.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters hmm, Y axis is between 0 and 1 where 1 is 100% accuracy. perhaps you can clarify what kind of scale more? For me the image appears with numbers on the Y axis, hmm maybe you don't see them?

Comment: Thanks darkmode :) It's not uncommon to have a small fluctuation, if I read the scale correctly the accuracy varies by +/- 2%. If you are really interested in the practical effect of the fluctuation, you could take two different models and see which images are classified differently.

Comment: Your validation curves are remarkably smooth. Do you have some sort of smoothing parameter set? How big is your validation set? If you're using mini batches for training and using a large validation set, this is expected behaviour. Are you evaluating on your validation set after each epoch? matplotlib could also be plotting a smooth curve for you if you're doing validation less frequently

Comment: @bbrodrigues no smoothing parameter. I use 0.63 dropout rate, but I assume it is because my validation set is as big as my training set.  Validation set is evaluated after each epoch. I added a picture of after augmentation on the training set. I use batch size of 128.